# $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}-3\geq k\left ( \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}{xy+yz+zx}-1 \right )$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, substitution, discriminant, uvw

Let $x,y,z>0$. Find the maximum value of $k$ such that the inequality $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}-3\geq k\left ( \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}{xy+yz+zx}-1 \right )$ is true for all $x,y,z>0$.

Here is my incorrect way to solve: Since the inequality is true for all $x,y,z>0$, let $b=c$ then we have $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}-2\geq k(\frac{x^2+2y^2}{2xy+y^2}-1)\Leftrightarrow \frac{(x-y)^2}{xy}\geq k\frac{(x-y)^2}{2xy+y^2}\Rightarrow k\leq \frac{2xy+y^2}{xy}=2+\frac{y}{x}$.

If we fix $y$, let $x\rightarrow +\infty $ then $k\leq 2$.
Howerver, the problem is that I can not prove the case $k=2$ is true and maybe the case $k=2$ is never true. And in my opinion, we must prove $k\leq1$ in any way. And the case $k=1$ is easy to solve.

Can anyone help me to show that $k\leq1$ please, thank all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k=1$ our inequality is true.

Thus, by your work $1\leq k_{max}\leq2.$

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2z-xyz)}{xyz}\geq\frac{k\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2-xy)}{xy+xz+yz}$$ or
$$v^2\sum_{cyc}(2x^2z-2xyz)\geq6k(u^2-v^2)w^3$$ or
$$v^2\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z-2xyz)-6k(u^2-v^2)w^3\geq v^2\sum_{cyc}x^2y-x^2z)$$ or
$$v^2(9uv^2-9w^3)-6k(u^2-v^2)w^3\geq v^2(x-y)(x-z)(y-z).$$ 
Now, for all $k\leq2$ we obtain:
$$v^2(9uv^2-9w^3)-6k(u^2-v^2)w^3\geq v^2(9uv^2-9w^3)-12(u^2-v^2)w^3=$$
$$=3(3uv^4-4u^2w^3+v^2w^3)\geq0$$ by $uvw$.

Indeed, the last inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$, which says it's enough to prove it for an extreme value of $w^3,$ which happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

In this case $3uv^4-4u^2w^3+v^2w^3\geq0$ is obviously true;

2. Two variables are equal.

Since this inequality is homogeneous, it's enough to assume that $y=z=1$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{(x+2)(2x+1)^2}{9}-\frac{4(x+2)^2x}{9}+\frac{(2x+1)x}{3}\geq0$$ or
$$(x-1)^2\geq0.$$
Id est, we proved that $$v^2(9uv^2-9w^3)-6k(u^2-v^2)w^3\geq0$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$\left(v^2(9uv^2-9w^3)-6k(u^2-v^2)w^3\right)^2\geq v^4\prod_{cyc}(x-y)^2$$ or
$$\left(3v^2(uv^2-w^3)-2k(u^2-v^2)w^3\right)^2\geq3v^4(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)$$ or
$$(k^2(u^2-v^2)^2+3kv^2(u^2-v^2)+3v^6)w^6+3uv^4(u^2-3v^2-k(u^2-v^2))w^3+3v^{10}\geq0.$$
Now, let $u^2=tv^2$.

Thus, $t\geq1$ and  if we want that our inequality will be true we need 
$$9t(t-3-k(t-1))^2-4\cdot3\cdot(k^2(t-1)^2+3k(t-1)+3)\leq0$$ or
$$(t-1)^2((3t-4)k^2-6(t-2)k+3(t-4))\leq0.$$

Let $t=\frac{4}{3}.$

Thus,$$(3t-4)k^2-6(t-2)k+3(t-4)=4k-8\leq0;$$
Let $1\leq t<\frac{4}{3}.$

Thus, we need to prove that $f(k)\geq0$ for all $1\leq k\leq 2$, where
$$f(k)=(4-3t)k^2-6(2-t)k+3(4-t),$$ which is true because
$$f(1)=4>0;$$
$$f(2)=4-3t>0$$ and $$\frac{3(2-t)}{4-3t}>1;$$
Let $t>\frac{4}{3}.$

Thus, we need 
$$(3t-4)k^2-6(t-2)k+3(t-4)\leq0,$$  for which we need
$$ k\leq\frac{3(t-2)+\sqrt{9(t-2)^2-3(3t-4)(t-4)}}{3t-4}$$ or
$$k\leq\frac{3(t-2)+2\sqrt{3(t-1)}}{3t-4},$$ which gives that we need
$$ k\leq\inf_{t>\frac{4}{3}}\frac{3(t-2)+2\sqrt{3(t-1)}}{3t-4}=1$$ and we are done!

Comment: Can you give me a full solution, it is not easy to understand the hint. @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Symmetric? Can you even write F given original LHS is not symmetric, only cyclic?

Comment: @Macavity Yes, I can. Wait please. I am posting a solution now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg : and if we want that our inequality will be true we need
9t(t−3−k(t−1))^2−4⋅3⋅(k(t−1)^2+3k(t−1)+3)≤0. Why you have that?

Comment: @user628755 Because $u^2=tv^2$ and discriminant should be non-negative. Let $a\neq0$. Thus, the fact that  $ax^2+bx+c\geq0$ for all real $x$ it's $a>0$ and $b^2-4ac\leq0.$

Comment: How great it is, thank so much!

Comment: But I wonder if there is another way to approach this problem...

Comment: @user628755 Maybe there is something easier because $k=1$ it's a simple value. But for $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}-3\geq\frac{k(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)}{(x+y+z)^2}$ it's an unique way.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I still have a problem here: when i calculate Delta, then use x^2=ty^2, I can not bring it to your delta

Comment: @user628755 See please better. We need to substitute $u^2=tv^2$ in $\left(3uv^4(u^2-3v^2-k(u^2-v^2))\right)^2-4(k(u^2-v^2)^2+3kv^2(u^2-v^2)+3v^6)\cdot3v^{10}\leq0.$